# Fluxo do OAuth 2.0 para autenticação de múltiplas APIs usando um servidor de autenticação

Tags: asp.net, api, asp.net-web-api, autenticação, oauth2

Ao realizar o login pela minha camada de front-end, é enviada uma requisição para o meu servidor de autenticação que, por sua vez, retorna um Bearer Token que pode vir a ser salvo em um cookie, por exemplo. Sem dúvidas quanto a isso!

O meu problema é que a minha camada de front faz requisições a  **N** outras APIs e eu preciso estar autenticado em todas elas, já que não posso liberar as rotas para receberem requisições sem estarem autenticadas.

Como devo planejar a autenticação?

Answer (score 0):

Você deve utilizar a mesma Machine Key em todas as API's

no Web.config da API onde você gera o token tem uma linha informando isso:

```
<system.web>
<machineKey 

validationKey="80F23AB9386C5D204479.............."              decryptionKey="5E26E9609FF8636A584A2C34671E..........." 
validation="SHA1" decryption="AES" />
</system.web>
```

Você utilizar esta mesma chave "MachineKey" nas outras API's que elas compartilharão o mesmo token.